Amazon sp-api marketplace
is there any way in the amazon sp-api to get the marketplace id of the refresh token. I want to know which marketplace's access the refresh token have?
I was trying the getmarketplaceparticipation end point but not able to get any response. I always get the 403 forbidden error, but actually the roles for which my developer app is authorized for have access to this endpoint.

What does the access token you get from the refresh token look like? Is it a JWT? Is there any useful information in the JWT payload?

If you're having trouble accessing an endpoint that you do have permission to use though you'll have to talk to AWS support directly. Does access need to be granted by the specific accounts too, i.e. does your customer need to individually give you permission to their getmarketplaceparticipation endpoint? I'm not sure how this works.

The token is linked not to a particular Amazon Marketplace, but to a precise Amazon Region. You can find regions and corresponding marketplaces on Amazon SP-API docs. These are:

North America (US, Canada, Mexico, Brazil)
Europe (all the EU + middle east marketplaces)
Far East (Singapore, Australia, Japan)

The region which is connected to the token depends on the Seller Central URL you used during the Authorization flow. You can find the complete list of Seller Central URL here.
As soon as you have a token, that is valid for each marketplace for that particular region. Remember that the SP-API endpoint is different for each region. You can find SP-API endpoints here. Check that you are currently using the right endpoint for the right region. If it is correct, then probably the problem stays here:

make sure that the AWS region used for the signature of the message matches with the region you are calling. Check marketplace - region link here.
make sure that all the required parameters are valid for the call you are making
check this link for more error diagnostic


Understood.
One more question.
Seller Central URL which is used is of North America region. It means the token is valid for US, Canada, Mexico and Brazil right?
So now during my testing, on the consent page I've selected the Canada marketplace and authorize it.
When i am trying to import the settlements it is importing the settlements from US marketplace but not from the Canada's marketplace.

The token Is valid for the whole region, in your case North America. Hence you will be able to perform calls for US, Canada, Mexico and Brazil marketplaces. Each call requires normally a marketplaceId parameter that sets from which marketplace you are retrieving data / to which marketplace you are sending data.

So now, the user of my application is trying to connect with my application. for the first time user connected the US marketplace for its first store. Now my application tends to show the settlements of its first store which is US. Now he wants to connect its Canada marketplace as a second store in my application so that he can view the settlements separately in my application.
Can you tell me the endpoint through which i can find out that this time for which marketplace user authorized for.
As now i understood that the token is valid for all the marketplaces in that region.

If the user authorized for US, he authorized you for the whole NA region (US + Canada + Mexico + Brazil). He doens't have to authorize you again. When, for example, you will call the createReport, you will set the US or Canada marketplaceId in the marketplaceIds parameter to gather data from only these two marketplaces.
